# How can I do to exclude some null values using queryset django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a queryset B and I want to exclude null values so I did that :

```
B.exclude(mycolumn__in[0, {"total": 0}])
```

because sometimes I can have JSON Field with null values. But I noticed that I can have that cases :

```
{"total": 0, "2": 0}])
```

or

```
{"total": 0, "5": 0}])
```

and like all the values are null I would like to exclude them also. How can I do that using `exclude()` ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Will there always be a dictionary stored in the JSON field?
Do you want to exclude rows if any value stored in the mycolumn dictionary is 0?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a django SQL operator to exclude null values.

```
B.filter(mycolumn__isnull=False)
```

To filter a Django SQL JSON field to exclude any JSON dict that has an outer level total key with a value of 0 use

```
B.exclude(mycolumn__total=0)
```

So to filter out null Json fields and Json fields with a value of 0 under the total key use:

```
B.exclude(my_column__isnull=True, my_column__total=0)
```

Here are the Django docs on querying JSONFields for reference.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield

Happy Coding!

Comment: I saw that but it does not work to exclude that : `{"total": 0, "5": 0}])`

Comment: Is it a json or jsonb field?

Comment: Will there always be a dictionary stored in the mycolumn field?

Comment: Yes it is a json field and it will be always a dictionnary stored. But what I want is exclude the entries which have all the values in the json filed null

Comment: @Tom Updated the answer with a query to exclude null values for the JSON along with JSON values with 'values = 0'